# two pieces of python code creates zip archive one of two is broken

Tags: python-3.x, io, zip

Initially I want to create zip file dynamically and return it in http response. I use python 3.7 lib  zipfile.
I tried both io buffer and tmp dir, neither one of them creates valid zip archive. Archive is only opened if its saved on disc
    import zipfile
    import io

```
#==============================================
# V1

file_like_object = io.BytesIO()

myZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile(file_like_object, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
myZipFile.writestr(u'test.py', b'test')

tmparchive="zip1.zip"

out = open(tmparchive,'wb') ## Open temporary file as bytes
out.write(file_like_object.getvalue())
out.close()

r = open(tmparchive, 'rb')
print (r.read())
r.close()

#==============================================



# V2

tmparchive2 = 'zip2.zip'

myZipFile2 = zipfile.ZipFile(tmparchive2, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
myZipFile2.writestr(u'test.py', b'test')

r2 = open(tmparchive2, 'rb')
print (r2.read())
r2.close()

#====================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to use a *context manager* like so:

```
import zipfile, io

file_like_object = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_like_object, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as myZipFile:
    myZipFile.writestr(u'test.txt', b'test')

# file_like_object.getvalue() are the bytes you send in your http response.
```

I wrote it to file. It's definitely a valid zip file.

If you want to open the archive, you need to save it to disk. Applications like Explorer and 7-Zip have no way to read the BytesIO object that exists in the `python` process. They can only open archives saved to disk.

Calling `print(r.read())` isn't going to open the archive. It's just going to print the bytes that make up the tiny zip file you just created.